# Convert query to parametrized asp.net query

Tags: asp.net

How would I make this parametrized ?!

```
string query = "";

            query += " SELECT DistID FROM Distributor";
            query += " WHERE Username = '" + username_id.Text + "'";
            query += " AND Password = '" + password.Text + "'";

            GeneralFunctions.GetData( query );
```

Can it be done here or would it have to be done inside the GetData method?

Here are the two methods:

```
public static DataTable GetData ( string query )
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    DataTable table;

    try
    {
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter( query, GetConnectionString() );
        table = new DataTable();

        dataAdapter.Fill( table );
        return table;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        dataAdapter = null;
        table = null;
    }

    return table;
}

public static string GetConnectionString ()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ "CAPortalConnectionString" ].ConnectionString;

    return connectionString;
}
```

Comment: @Aristos I have no idea what DAL's are.  This is a learning project for me, im making the leap from classic asp to asp.net.  Is the code above not a good example for getting sql data and a connection string?

Comment: That's a good bit of sifting thru google and assumes you recognise good, 99% of the examples are more like the code he's trying to change :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The code above is not good?  How would it be made good?

Comment: No usings and poor exception handling for starters, and why is GetConnectionString public?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I should make that private.  I don't even know what usings are yet.  But I will add that to my list of things to learn. :)

Comment: @Darin's is good. Public methods where you pass in a sql string, will make any code quality checker, run around the office screaming. I know the general query thing looks like a good idea, done it myself, but it never works out that way. Write methods that just do and get what you want

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Well I learned something today, hopefully I can understand all of this more and more as time goes on.  I am now using Darin's method, and will formulate future things after it.  You all rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you designing specific methods to query your database, like this:

```
public static int? GetDistID(string username, string password)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = 
        @"SELECT 
              DistID 
          FROM 
              Distributor
          WHERE 
              Username = @username 
          AND 
              Password = @password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                // no results found
                return null;
            }
            return reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("DistID"));
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var distId = GeneralFunctions.GetDistID(username_id.Text, password.Text);
```

No need of DataTables/Sets/Adapters. Work with strongly typed objects.

Comment: Could you help me understand some parts of it, like the `int?`

I also assume I would place this in my `GeneralFunctions` and call it on my login page like `GetDistID(username_id.Text, password.Text)`

`if (reader.Read())
authenticate

else don't authenticate is that.  Altho it will return null maybe if reader != null?`

I think I understand the rest.

Comment: `int?` is an alias for `Nullable<int>` and means nullable integer. I use it because the function could return null in the case no record is found in the database that matches the username and password. If the signature of the method was simply `int GetDistID()` you can't return null because Int32 is a value type. When you call `reader.Read()` it advances the reader to the next row that was found in the database corresponding to your criteria and it returns a boolean value indicating whether there are more rows.

Comment: Have a plus. If you had put doc coments in I would have logged in as someone else and given you another one.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  Thank you very much, this is a learning project for me.  I appreciate your willingness to help a noob out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SqlCommand` object, and you can create a parameterized query like this:

```
public object GetDistID(string username, string password)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DistID FROM Distributor WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", conn))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);                
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

If it's useful to you, here's a class you can use. It's tailored towards stored procedures, but it should be easy enough to add a method that accepts a query:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace NESCTC.Data
{  
    public class DataAccess : IDisposable
    {
        #region declarations

        private SqlCommand _cmd;
        private string _SqlConnString;

        #endregion

        #region constructors

        public DataAccess(string ConnectionString)
        {
            _cmd = new SqlCommand();
            _cmd.CommandTimeout = 240;
            _SqlConnString = ConnectionString;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable implementation

        ~DataAccess()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);            
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _cmd.Connection.Dispose();
                _cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region data retrieval methods

        public DataTable ExecReturnDataTable()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    PrepareCommandForExecution(conn);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        adap.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }    

        public object ExecScalar()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    PrepareCommandForExecution(conn);
                    return _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }                

        #endregion

        #region data insert and update methods

        public void ExecNonQuery()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    PrepareCommandForExecution(conn);
                    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region helper methods

        public void AddParm(string ParameterName, SqlDbType ParameterType, object Value)
        { _cmd.Parameters.Add(ParameterName, ParameterType).Value = Value; }

        private SqlCommand PrepareCommandForExecution(SqlConnection conn)
        {
            try
            {
                _cmd.Connection = conn;
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _cmd.CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout;
                _cmd.Connection.Open();

                return _cmd;
            }
            catch
            {
                _cmd.Connection.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region properties

        public int CommandTimeout
        {
            get { return _cmd.CommandTimeout; }
            set { _cmd.CommandTimeout = value; }
        }

        public string ProcedureName
        {
            get { return _cmd.CommandText; }
            set { _cmd.CommandText = value; }
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return _SqlConnString; }
            set { _SqlConnString = value; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You can use the class like this:

```
public object GetDistID(string username, string password)
{
    using (var data = new DataAccess("ConnectionString"))
    {
        data.ProcedureName = "GetDistID";
        data.AddParm("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, username);
        data.AddParm("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, password);
        return data.ExecScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I understood what all this is doing better.  I am starring this and going to try and put it to use if I can understand it.  Thank you very much for your answer.