# C# String to DateTime Conversion issue Using ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am fetching date from textbox and passing it to dateTime by passing it though a function,

**BUT it gives me two different results**

```cs
DateTime Fromdate1 = devTools.ParseDate(datepicker1.Text);
```

TextBox --->OutPut

02/09/2012 --> 2/9/2012 12:00:00 AM

30/08/2012 --> 8/30/2012 12:00:00 AM

```cs
public DateTime ParseDate(string s)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(s, out result))
        {
            string[] formats = { "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy" };
            result = DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
            //result = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            //result = result.AddDays(1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

What is the problem here,Is there a prper way to get constant output type,also it will create problems in DB since 08/09 will be checked against 09/08 and vice versa !

**One more problem in SQL :**

```
Select convert(nchar(10),FromDate, 103) AS FromDate,convert(nchar(10),ToDate, 103) AS ToDate FROM Tbl_PropertyRoomSeasonPrices
```

OUTPUT :

28/08/2012  |   09/01/2012

dd/mm/yyyy  |   mm/dd/yyyy
(CORRECT)       (WRONG)

but 103 for fromDate and 101 for toDate makes it both same,Why the variations ??

Comment: Why do you think that there's a problem here? The `ParseExact` function has correctly parsed the string to a DateTime instance. Once you have a valid DateTime instance ADO.NET will take care of properly persisting it to the database (assuming you are using parametrized queries of course or an ORM).

Comment: bcos in db first value is saved as dd/MM but second gets saved as MM/dd

Comment: What data type are you using in your database? I hope you are not storing datetimes in a varchar column?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov No its DateTime,its SQL2005 and i Think the sql statements all need to be parameterised to accomplish this like **WHERE ( (convert(datetime, '" + FromDate + "', 101) between (convert(datetime, FromDate , 101) and convert(datetime, ToDate, 101))**

Comment: Oh, I see, that's your problem. Don't use string concatenations when building your SQL queries. Use parametrized queries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10144157/29407

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can you pls advice me how parametrized queries will help me here.

Comment: @sajanyamaha: By including the value as a parameter, still as a `DateTime`, instead of converting it to a string. The value in the `DateTime` is correct - it's the conversion back to a string which sounds like it's causing you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the "problem" here is just how you're interpreting the output. Your method returns a `DateTime` - not a string - so when you've written. "02/09/2012 --> 2/9/2012 12:00:00 AM" you presumably mean that an input of string "02/09/2012" gives you a result `DateTime` which *happens to have a string representation* of "2/9/2012 12:00:00 AM" in whatever way you're converting it to a string, e.g. by looking in the debugger. That will use the current culture and the default format - but that's not part of the `DateTime` value itself.

Look at the properties of the `DateTime` and you'll see it's been parsed correctly.

> also it will create problems in DB since 08/09 will be checked against 09/08 and vice versa

No it won't. Not if you're doing things properly - using parameterized SQL and specifying the `DateTime` value for the property. It could well give you problems if you're including the value directly in your SQL, but that's a bad idea anyway.

Comment: but is there any way to output it as 30/08/2012 12:00:00 AM rather than 8/30/2012 12:00:00 AM

Comment: you mean in SQL like : **WHERE ( (convert(datetime, '" + FromDate + "', 101) between (convert(datetime, FromDate , 101) and convert(datetime, ToDate, 101))** ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha if you are asking way to convert output, it should be like dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @sajanyamaha, you need to use parametrized queries instead of building your SQL with string concatenations.

Comment: @sajanyamaha: Yes, you can easily specify a custom date format, but you *really* shouldn't be doing that to build SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet : **One more problem in SQL :**


    Select convert(nchar(10),FromDate, 103) AS FromDate,convert(nchar(10),ToDate, 103) AS ToDate FROM Tbl_PropertyRoomSeasonPrices

OUTPUT :

28/08/2012  | 09/01/2012

dd/mm/yyyy  |   mm/dd/yyyy  
(CORRECT)       (WRONG)

but 103 for fromDate and 101 for toDate makes it both same,Why the variations ??

Comment: @sajanyamaha: Why are you converting in SQL at all? Just don't do it - fetch it *as a DateTime*. Avoid string conversions wherever you can.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to bind it to a gridview label Text in dd/mm/yyyy format as **Text='<%# Eval("FromDate") %>'**

Answer (score 0):

Try using overloaded Parse methods which accept IFormatProvider;
For example;

```
DateTime.TryParse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now, new string[]{ "dd/MM/yyyy" }, ...);
```